# How to create a Virtual Android device 800x400 that I can see on my laptop?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to create a virtual device (nexus one) with wvga800, 800x480 but when I do, I can't see the whole screen on my 13" macbook pro, and I can't scroll down to see the bottom of the screen.  How can I see the bottom of my virtual phone screen???
thanks,

Answer (score 8):

You can scale your emulator window, to more closely match the actual device size. This is an option when you run the emulator from the Android SDK and AVD Manager. This is the window you get from running the `android` command, or from Window|Android SDK and AVD Manager in Eclipse.

Not only will this give you an emulator window closer in size to what the actual device is (so you do not assume people can necessarily click on too-small buttons, etc.), but it will also fit your screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually possible from your project as well, no need to start the emulator through the manager:

1) go to Run > Run Configurations... > (Select your application on the left hand side) > (Click the "Target" tab on the right hand side). 
2) At the bottom there, you'll see 'Emulator launch parameters'. In the 'additional emulator command line options', add '-scale 0.75' (to make the screen 75% of full size)

Next time you start the emulator it will have scaled properly, hooray!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it, you have to START the emulator from the AVD Manager, after you hit the 'START' button, another window pops up allowing you to set the size of the emulator display.
If you run a project from eclipse, you will not get that screen to set the size of the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

To view full emulator make use of it's full screen mode using alt+enter keys on windows & Linux. But, for mac I'm not sure b'cos i have not checked for it; it has to be same like making your media player window full screen. Please do check for mac & update my post.